# cache gets lost when duplicating a scene

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, scene, cache

I have a scene with a Cloth Simulation and I want to duplicate the scene (new scene/full copy). The problem is that the cache is not duplicated. My idea was to store the cache externally (disk cache) so that I could link the folder with the cache manually. But I can't find an option where I could link the cache. I am not getting anywhere right now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Most caches can be specified to be placed in a particular folder of your choice.  If you keep exploring here on BSE and the cache panel you will see a place to specify the folder.  You can copy files within a cache.  Please beware of unintentionally changing parameters of shared cache data because you may delete/replace data and have to create it again.   If you place an image of the cache panel in your question you may see text fields for the specification of the folder

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html ...  latest means 3.3 today.  You may want to state which version of Blender is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the baked cache, in addition to activating the "Disk cache" option, you need to assign a name to the cache, after bake physics, and after full copy scene, you can load the cache with "Current Cache to Bake" button.

[image]